# How to remove a string from a list that startswith prefix in python

Tags: python, string, list, startswith

I have this list of strings and some prefixes. I want to remove all the strings from the list that start with any of these prefixes. I tried:

```
prefixes = ('hello', 'bye')
list = ['hi', 'helloyou', 'holla', 'byeyou', 'hellooooo']
for word in list:
    list.remove(word.startswith(prexixes)
```

So I want my new list to be:

```
list = ['hi', 'holla']
```

but I get this error:

```
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Greg's solution is definitely more Pythonic, but in your original code, you perhaps meant something like this. Observe that we make a copy (using `list[:]` syntax) and iterate over the copy, because you should not modify a list while iterating over it.

```
prefixes = ('hello', 'bye')
list = ['hi', 'helloyou', 'holla', 'byeyou', 'hellooooo']
for word in list[:]:
    if word.startswith(prefixes):
        list.remove(word)
print list
```

Comment: Even though Gregs answer may heve been more pythonic, I accapted this answer, because ths was precisely what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, thanks for that answer.
Sorry for digging out this old post, but could you explain why this produces the wrong result when using
`for word in list:`
instead of
`for word in list[:]:`

Comment: @nik.yan I am very curious about this as well. I tested running `for word in list` and noticed that some of the strings that contained a prefix weren't being removed. However, when I tried `for word in list[:]`, all the correct string were being removed.

Comment: I think it's because Python internally tracks the index for the loop, and when you remove an element, the index isn't updated so it skips over items.

Answer (score 36):

You can create a new list that contains all the words that do *not* start with one of your prefixes:

```
newlist = [x for x in list if not x.startswith(prefixes)]
```

The reason your code does not work is that the `startswith` method returns a boolean, and you're asking to remove that boolean from your list (but your list contains strings, not booleans).

Note that it is usually not a good idea to name a variable `list`, since this is already the name of the predefined `list` type.

Comment: Hey, I learned that `startswith` can take a tuple as a parameter. Cool!

Comment: I didn't actually use list as a variable name, it was just as an example here. This worked for me btw :)

Comment: And yes startswith can take tuples as a parameter as of python 2.5 :)

Comment: Thanks, I should use not more :) ...... NOT (haha, sorry for my poor sense of humor)

Answer (score 0):

```
print len([i for i in os.listdir('/path/to/files') if not i.startswith(('.','~','#'))])
```